# windows start service failure on logging as different user?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've logged into the visual studio as a different user while debugging the project encountered with error as:

> "Windows service start failure"

But when I run with my own credentials working fine. I've tried by giving admin permissions to the particular user on the service but the result is same as below.

Can anyone help me on this?.

[click here to see the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJOJg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your service has a '**ServiceProcessInstaller**' (right-click designer-surface of your service.cs and select 'Add Installer'), then change the account property for the service process installer to whatever suits your needs best (Network Service, Local System or Local Service). You may also need to specify the startup type of the service installer class.

To install it do the following steps:

1. Run Visual Studio Command Prompt as administrator.
2. Change the directory to the output directory of the service (where the executable file is located) - '**cd C:\directory**'
3. Perform the following command '**installutil service_name.exe**'

The service should then startup based on the startup type you specified. You may need to start it manually.